# Batch Insert using a loop to add to table storage in windows azure

Tags: asp.net, batch-processing, azure-table-storage

I am trying to do a batch insert from a list of objects to table storage in Windows Azure.

I am using the storage emulator for now. 
I get this error:

> "Unexpected response code for operation".

I tried to search for anyone who encountered similar problems but to no avail.

My keys are setup this way:

```
PartitionKey = "projects" + CompanyID.toString(); 
RowKey = ProjectID.toString();
```

It is inserted like this:

```
foreach (vProject item in projectList) 
        {
            TableOperation retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<mMultipleSave.ViewProjectEntity>("projects" + CompanyID.toString(), item.ProjectID.ToString());

            TableResult retrievedResult = table.Execute(retrieveOperation);

            if (retrievedResult.Result != null)
            {
                mMultipleSave.ViewProjectEntity updateEntity = (mMultipleSave.ViewProjectEntity)retrievedResult.Result;
                if (!item.isProjectArchived)
                {
                    //update entity in table storage
                    updateEntity.ProjectClient = item.ClientName;
                    updateEntity.ProjectCompany = item.Company;
                    updateEntity.ProjectName = item.ProjectName;
                    batchUpdateOperation.Replace(updateEntity);
                }
                else {
                    //delete project in table storage if it is archived in the database
                    batchDeleteOperation.Delete(updateEntity);
                }
            }
            else //if it does not exist in table storage insert
            {
                mMultipleSave.ViewProjectEntity entity = new mMultipleSave.ViewProjectEntity(CompanyID, item.ProjectID);

                entity.ProjectClient = item.ClientName;
                entity.ProjectCompany = item.Company;
                entity.ProjectName = item.ProjectName;

                batchInsertOperation.Insert(entity);

            }
        }
        if (batchInsertOperation.Count > 0)
            table.ExecuteBatch(batchInsertOperation);
        if (batchUpdateOperation.Count > 0)
            table.ExecuteBatch(batchUpdateOperation);
        if (batchDeleteOperation.Count > 0)
            table.ExecuteBatch(batchDeleteOperation);
```

It gets an error on `table.ExecuteBatch(batchInsertOperation);`

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. Update your windows azure tools including the emulator to the latest version. As of today, it is in version 2.0